# Ubuntu One File Sync Error

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

Today I am going to share my file to Ubuntu one, but having problem with sync, file sync error, click after restart button, it's showing same result

[image]

Comment: I ended up emailing my file in the end, I just could not understand any of the answers provided. In the end it was just as easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/419924/file-sync-error-auth-failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419924/file-sync-error-auth-failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the solution on [here](http://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-does-the-root_mismatch-error-mean/).
This happens when running two accounts on the same machine. The following steps will help clean this up.

Press Alt-F2, type "seahorse", press "Enter"

Right-click on any "Ubuntu One" and "Desktopcouch" entries and select "Delete"

Press Alt-F2, type "gnome-terminal" or "terminal", press "Enter" and run:

```
u1sdtool -q; sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone; u1sdtool -c;
```