# File sync error (AUTH_FAILED)

Tags: ubuntu-one

Recently I started getting a File sync error on all 3 of my PCs running Ubuntu One.  One is running Ubuntu, the other 2 are running Windows 8.  Looking at the list of clients on the web, none of them were there anymore.

I found this article:

[Ubuntu One : Help : FAQs—What should I do if authentication fails? (AUTH_FAILED state)](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-should-i-do-if-authentication-fails-auth_failed-state)

On how to fix the issue for my Ubuntu PC and it worked perfectly.  Now I am looking for a similar fix for Windows but haven't found one yet.  I've tried un-installing Ubuntu One and re-installing it, but it must still be holding the keys somewhere because it never asked me to login again.

Does anyone know where I can clear these keys to get my files syncing on Windows again?

Comment: Under Windows XP, I had to delete the registry key and that fixed my problem.

Comment: I had the exact same error on Ubuntu and had to remove the Ubuntu One key under my Passwords & Keys. then I could restart Ubuntu One file Sync (top right button) and re-login. Everything up and running again now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows 8 you should be able to find the Ubuntu One token by using Windows Vault to manage credentials. This should be the same on Windows 7 as well.

On Windows XP, the registry editor must be used, and you have to remove the token under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ubuntu One\Keyring\`.

On Ubuntu, you can open the `Passwords and Keys` application from the dash, or from `System Settings`, then find the `Ubuntu One` token entry and delete it.

After, open the Ubuntu One control panel application again, and log in, and you should be connected again.

Comment: Thanks!  I found it specifically at 
Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager.

Comment: Also before this answer, I was able to resolve my problem by running c:\Program Files (x86)\ubuntuone\dist\ubuntu-sso-login-qt.exe and logging in again.  Being new here, I was unable to answer my own question right away, though.