# UbuntuOne Auth failed

Tags: xubuntu, ubuntu-one, sync

I have a dual boot notebook (windows 7 and Xubuntu 12.04).
The Ubuntu one client is installed on both systems, each one with a different sync folder (c:\user\a\ubuntu one, home/b/ubuntu one)

UbuntuOne client was running fine until I booted Windows where I got an error from UbuntuOne client. So I upgraded UbuntuOne client, started the synch process and it worked.

When I booted Ubuntu again I get a "File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))".

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419924/file-sync-error-auth-failed) but I can't find the 'Passwords and Keys application' in Xubuntu both from the Accessory or from System Settings.

I have tried a completely re-install of the UbuntuOne client but it was unsuccessful.

I think that the issue might be due to a different user files owner (a on windows7, b on Ubuntu).

How can I fix it?

Should I remove the UbuntuOne client for Windows7 and get only the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced something very similar on Ubuntu 13.10 when adding new devices which is logged at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1253728
For me the workaround was really odd but consistant on 3 different computers as I was doing some moving, adding, and re-installing on several (only two as of the writing of that post).  I found that I had to click some things that seemed contrary to logic but everthing worked fine every time.

1. Started the client and it seemed frozen at "Getting information,
   please wait..."
2. Killed the client and restarted it.
3. This time it asked me to log in so I did so with my existing account (as
   if it were new).
4. It displayed "Getting information" but I just
   clicked next anyway.
5. Confirmed the folder selections.
6. After this it displayed the authentication error but after I clicked restart
   everything was fine and it has been working since then.

Comment: Thank you Dennis.
I followed your action list but I get the same error.

My workaround:

 1. Install seahorse and delete UbuntuOne Password and Key. 
 2. Remove     ~/local/share/ubuntuone
 3. sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates ([here][1])
 4. user logout & login
 5. Started UbuntuOne client with my login information and everything was ok.

  [1]: http://%20https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-am-i-getting-an-the-authentication-failed-error-on-windows/